# Protecting elderly parents - how to screen calls, sms and email?

Tags: security

After having a parent scammed and realizing they are not quite able to discern between scammers and everyone else I need to do something. Taking away their phone isn't an option because quality of life is higher for having access. So I'm looking for a way to screen the attack vectors I can't protect with other means.

Specifically:

- redirect all phone calls from numbers not on a whitelist (contacts for example)
- redirect all sms in the same way
- redirect emails (that are not thrown into spam and are not from known contacts).

Ideally I could "approve" sms and emails to be sent back to them. If I could add the calller to their whitelist automatically would be even better.

Comment: I'd look at Twilio to handle the first two of your points. Their interface would allow relatively simple development of flows for incoming calls or messages (can be as simple as the presence of a file on the web server gives a 200 or 404 and that decides the routing; could be as complicated as a web API you develop to make intelligent choices and implement workflows).